# Error 2465 when trying to assign recordset value to control on subform in report

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I am trying to fill 5 sub forms(Fr_Rep_x)(x=1 to 5) in a report(Report1) with recordset values(5 different pages) by invoking a public function 5 times.
The subforms and the public function are invoked in the report_activate event

I am getting the above error 2465: Application-defined or object-defined error
on the below line of the public function:

> ```
> Reports("Report1").fr_name.Controls(Lbl_ON).Caption = rst("Order_Number")
> ```

Report Activate Event

```
Private Sub Report_Activate()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 5
        DoCmd.OpenForm "Fr_Rep_" & i, , , , , acHidden
        Call MORep(i, Forms!Fr_Main!NavSubform.Form!Lbox_Comp.Column(0), "00" & i & "0", Forms!Fr_Main!NavSubform.Form!Lbox_Comp.Column(3))
    Next i
End Sub
```

Public Function

```
Public Sub MORep(Form_num As Integer, MO_ON As Long, MO_Op As String, Mat As String)
Dim fr_name As String
fr_name = "Fr_Rep_" & Form_num

var_order = MO_ON
var_op_n = MO_Op
var_mat = Mat
var_matdes = DLookup("Material_Description", "Tbl_MO_Rev_Control", "Material = '" & var_mat & "'")
var_matrev = DLookup("MO_Rev_No", "Tbl_MO_List_Archive", "Order_Number = " & var_order)

Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Set dbs = CurrentDb()
Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("Tbl_MO_List_Archive", Type:=dbOpenDynaset)
rst.FindFirst "[Order_Number] = " & var_order '& "*'" & "AND MO_Rev_No ='" & var_mo_rev & ""
Dim str1
Reports("Report1").fr_name.Controls(Lbl_ON).Caption = rst("Order_Number")
Reports("Report1").fr_name.Form.Lbl_OQ.Caption = rst("Order_Qty")
Reports("Report1").fr_name.Form.Lbl_Batch.Caption = rst("Batch")
Reports("Report1").fr_name.Form.Lbl_MRP.Caption = rst("MRP_Controller")
Reports("Report1").fr_name.Form.Lbl_PC.Caption = rst("Profit_Center")
Reports("Report1").fr_name.Form.Lbl_PS.Caption = rst("Production_Scheduler")
Reports("Report1").fr_name.Form.Lbl_Mat.Caption = rst("Material")
Reports("Report1").fr_name.Form.Lbl_Pr_D.Caption = Format(rst("MO_Issue_Date"), "DD-MMM-YYYY")
Reports("Report1").fr_name.Form.Lbl_Pr_T.Caption = rst("MO_Issue_Time")

Set rst = Nothing

Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_Mat_D).Caption = var_matdes
Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_T_Pg).Caption = DLookup("Total_Pages", "Tbl_MO_Rev_Control", "MO_Rev_No = '" & var_matrev & "'")
Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_SAP).Caption = "Form # " & DLookup("SAP_Form_no", "Tbl_MO_Rev_Control", "MO_Rev_No = '" & var_matrev & "'")

Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("Tbl_MO_Op_Archive", Type:=dbOpenDynaset)
rst.FindFirst "[Order_Number] = " & var_order '& "*'" & "AND MO_Rev_No ='" & var_mo_rev & ""

If var_op_n = "0010" Then
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_Ver_Drw_T).Visible = True
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_Ver_Drw_B).Visible = True
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_Ver_Drw_Sign).Visible = True
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_Ver_Drw_Dt).Visible = True
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_Pg).Caption = rst("10_Page_No")
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_Ver_Drw_Sign).Caption = rst("10_Verif_Drw_Rev_Stamp")
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_Ver_Drw_Dt).Caption = rst("10_Verif_Drw_Rev_Date_Stamp")
        'hide stamp labels for op 0020 to 0050
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_FPV).Visible = False
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_Clk).Visible = False
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_Sign_Date).Visible = False
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_VS_Acc).Visible = False
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_VS_Rej).Visible = False
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_PC_NA).Visible = False
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Img_VS_Stamp).Visible = False
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_Stamp_Type).Visible = False
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_PC_Stamp).Visible = False
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_PC_Acc).Visible = False
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_PC_Rej).Visible = False
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_Rej).Visible = False
ElseIf var_op_n = "0020" Then
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_FPV).Visible = True
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_Clk).Visible = True
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_Sign_Date).Visible = True
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_VS_Acc).Visible = True
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_VS_Rej).Visible = True
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_PC_NA).Visible = True
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_PC_Acc).Visible = True
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_PC_Rej).Visible = True
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_Rej).Visible = True

    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_Ver_Drw_T).Visible = False
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_Ver_Drw_B).Visible = False
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_Ver_Drw_Sign).Visible = False
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_Ver_Drw_Dt).Visible = False
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_Pg).Caption = rst("20_Page_No")
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_FPV).Caption = rst("20_First_Pc_Verif_Stamp")
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_Clk).Caption = rst("20_Clock_No_Stamp")
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_Sign_Date).Caption = rst("20_Date_Stamp")
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_VS_Acc).Caption = rst("20_Sample_Verif_Acc_Stamp")
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_VS_Rej).Caption = rst("20_Sample_Verif_Rej_Stamp")
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_PC_NA).Caption = rst("20_Verif_Stamp_Type")          'user stamp not stored in 0020 op, only NA comment
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_PC_Acc).Caption = rst("20_Pc_Comp_Acc_Stamp")
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_PC_Rej).Caption = rst("20_Pc_Comp_Rej_Stamp")
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_Rej).Caption = rst("20_Reject_No_Stamp")
ElseIf var_op_n = "0030" Then
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Img_VS_Stamp).Visible = False
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_Stamp_Type).Visible = False
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_PC_Stamp).Visible = False
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_Pg).Caption = rst("30_Page_No")
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_FPV).Caption = rst("30_First_Pc_Verif_Stamp")
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_Clk).Caption = rst("30_Clock_No_Stamp")
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_Sign_Date).Caption = rst("30_Date_Stamp")
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_VS_Acc).Caption = rst("30_Sample_Verif_Acc_Stamp")
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_VS_Rej).Caption = rst("30_Sample_Verif_Rej_Stamp")
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_PC_NA).Caption = rst("30_Verif_Stamp_Type")          'user stamp not stored in 0030 op, only NA comment
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_PC_Acc).Caption = rst("30_Pc_Comp_Acc_Stamp")
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_PC_Rej).Caption = rst("30_Pc_Comp_Rej_Stamp")
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_Rej).Caption = rst("30_Reject_No_Stamp")
ElseIf var_op_n = "0040" Then
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_Pg).Caption = rst("40_Page_No")
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_FPV).Caption = rst("40_First_Pc_Verif_Stamp")
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_Clk).Caption = rst("40_Clock_No_Stamp")
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_Sign_Date).Caption = rst("40_Date_Stamp")
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_VS_Acc).Caption = rst("40_Sample_Verif_Acc_Stamp")
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_VS_Rej).Caption = rst("40_Sample_Verif_Rej_Stamp")
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_PC_Stamp).Caption = rst("40_Verification_Stamp")                     'user stamp IS stored in 0040 op
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_Stamp_Type).Caption = rst("40_Verif_Stamp_Type")                     'user stamp IS stored in 0040 op
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_PC_Acc).Caption = rst("40_Pc_Comp_Acc_Stamp")
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_PC_Rej).Caption = rst("40_Pc_Comp_Rej_Stamp")
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_Rej).Caption = rst("40_Reject_No_Stamp")
ElseIf var_op_n = "0050" Then
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Img_VS_Stamp).Visible = False
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_Stamp_Type).Visible = False
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_PC_Stamp).Visible = False
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_Pg).Caption = rst("50_Page_No")
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_FPV).Caption = rst("50_First_Pc_Verif_Stamp")
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_Clk).Caption = rst("50_Clock_No_Stamp")
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_Sign_Date).Caption = rst("50_Date_Stamp")
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_VS_Acc).Caption = rst("50_Sample_Verif_Acc_Stamp")
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_VS_Rej).Caption = rst("50_Sample_Verif_Rej_Stamp")
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_PC_NA).Caption = rst("50_Verif_Stamp_Type")          'user stamp not stored in 0030 op, only NA comment
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_PC_Acc).Caption = rst("50_Pc_Comp_Acc_Stamp")
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_PC_Rej).Caption = rst("50_Pc_Comp_Rej_Stamp")
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_Rej).Caption = rst("50_Reject_No_Stamp")
End If

If Form_num = 5 Then
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing
End If

If var_op_n = "0020" Or var_op_n = "0050" Then
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_FPV).Top = 5250
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_Clk).Vertical = False
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_Clk).Top = 5250
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_Sign_Date).Top = 5250
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_VS_Acc).Top = 5250
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_VS_Rej).Top = 5250
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_PC_NA).Top = 5250
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_PC_Acc).Top = 5250
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_PC_Rej).Top = 5250
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_Rej).Top = 5250
Else
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_FPV).Top = 7250
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_Clk).Vertical = True
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_Clk).Top = 7250
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_Sign_Date).Top = 7250
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_VS_Acc).Top = 7250
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_VS_Rej).Top = 7250
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_PC_NA).Top = 7250
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_PC_Acc).Top = 7250
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_PC_Rej).Top = 7250
    Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_Rej).Top = 7250
End If

Call OpNum
Call MatNum
Call MatRev
'Forms(fr_name)(Lbox_Op_List).Requery
'Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbox_Op).Requery
Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_Op).Caption = DLookup("Operation_Description", "Tbl_Ops_Desc", "MO_Rev_No = '" & var_matrev & "' AND Oper_No ='" & var_op_n & "'")

End Sub
```

[Report Structure and Code movement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2gyA.png) Getting stuck at step 6, All forms have same controls and control names

please advice, I guess the report subform control referencing is wrong?

Comment: Please add `Option Explicit` to your modules and compile the code, probably you made a mistake in variable names. As I understand, instead of `fr_name.Controls` should be `fr_name.Form.Controls`. Whal is `Lbl_ON`?

Comment: This look overly complicated and probably unnecessary.  I'm mystified by the need to move controls around within a form. Just hided / unhide as required, you can sit them on top of each other if you *really* need multiple controls. Also You can use the tag property to loop around sets of controls and enable / change them.

Comment: @Minty I have edited the question to include the Report structure and code movement. I had to do this as all subforms are copies of each other with same control name and just the control values are being changed in each subform.

Comment: @Sergey S. adding `Option Explicit` stops the code on `Forms(fr_name).Controls(Lbl_Mat_D).Caption = var_matdes` and required me to define `Lbl_Mat_D` as a variable when it actually is a control name; I have corrected the `fr_name.Controls` to 'fr_name.Form.Controls' the report is poping up but the recordset values are not getting assigned to any of the subforms

Comment: @Sergey S. `Lbl_ON` is the name of a control on the form _Label OrderNumber_ I have edited the question to include the Report structure and code movement. All subforms are copies of each other with same control name and just the control values are being changed in each subform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As to your code, `Lbl_ON` has not been assigned a value here:

```
Reports("Report1").fr_name.Controls(Lbl_ON).Caption = rst("Order_Number")
```

To check, insert a debug line. Also, try specifying the *Value* property:

```
Debug.Print "Lbl_ON:", Lbl_ON
Reports("Report1").fr_name.Controls(Lbl_ON).Caption = rst("Order_Number").Value
```

If Lbl_ON can be *Null*, there is no control to access, thus:

```
If Not IsNull(Lbl_ON) then
    Reports("Report1").fr_name.Controls(Lbl_ON).Caption = rst("Order_Number").Value
End If
```

That will, of course, not adjust anything, so you will wish to correct that `Lbl_ON` has no value.

Comment: Tried the above but error still occurs, debug gives `Lbl_ON:   (Null)`, but in vba debug mode it shows `rst("Order_Number").Value` has retrieved a value from table successfully

Comment: I have edited the question to include the Report structure and code movement. All subforms are copies of each other with same control name and just the control values are being changed in each subform

Comment: Earlier error was occuring at first control of Subform2, Now error occurs at first control of subform1!...`Reports("Report1").fr_name.Form.Lbl_ON.Caption = rst("Order_Number").Value` or `Reports("Report1").fr_name.Controls(Lbl_ON).Caption = rst("Order_Number").Value` does not resolve the error!

Comment: To avoid an error caused by Null values, see my edited answer, please.

Comment: Nz has no effect ...Error recurs

Comment: That is right. I've edited the answer. But how to resolve the issue - that `Lbl_ON` has not been assigned a value - is up to you.

Comment: `fr_name` is a string variable, you need to address it as `.Controls(fr_name)` as well. `.fr_name` cannot work. @Tinker

Comment: @Andre That was the right thing...got it working...this is how it should be to work...`Reports![Report1].Controls(fr_name).Form.Lbl_ON.Caption`